# why does git-lfs on Windows fail with "executable file not found in %PATH%"?

Tags: windows, git, git-lfs

I'm using git-lfs on Windows; just did my first fetch of an LFS file and got this error: `Error downloading object: test-resources/CreateReferenceForMedia-flat.tiff (e26806d): Smudge error: Error downloading test-resources/CreateReferenceForMedia-flat.tiff (e26806d26938600c50a56ca03e3ec559ebd3d9cad1442b0a71cbfebbc166e53c): batch request: executable file not found in %PATH%`

There is a logfile with a stack trace (looks like go code), but doesn't say what executable it is looking for.
I do have git-lfs, ssh and git on %PATH%. I'm running from an msys shell btw.
What executable is it looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try again with:

- the [latest Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.39.1+)
- a CMD where you set a simplified PATH (for testing)

Open a CMD and type:

```bash
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set "GH=%ProgramFiles%\Git"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

Check that where git-lfs.exe does return

```bash
C:\Users\vonc> where git-lfs.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git-lfs.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git-lfs.exe
```

From there, cd to your repository folder, type `bash` if you want, and runs `git lfs` again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case it was an invalid path for env variable `GIT_SSH` - instead of '\' I had '/'. After I fixed this variable the problem disappeared.